# Why "do while" loop keeps exiting, even though the condition evaluates to false?

Tags: c++

When I run the code it should only make the win `condition = true` after either all dragons have no health or all ships have no health.
But when it runs, it seems the do while loop exits after the first iteration, even though the condition is set to only leave while win condition is true.
I cannot seem to figure out why it wont continue running, I even assigned `winCondition = false` when declaring the variable.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct ship  //Creates type ship
{
  float shipHealth;
  int numOfPeople;
  bool capturedDragon;
};

struct dragon  //Creates type dragon
{
  string riderName;
  string dragonName;
  float dragonHealth;
  bool isCaptured = false;
};

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  const int MAX_SHIPS = 7;
  const int MAX_RIDERS = 5;

  int dragonHit;
  int dragonDamage;
  int dragonRemoveMenNumber;
  int shipDamage;
  int shipHit;
  bool winCondition = false;

  ship hunterShips[MAX_SHIPS];  //creates array of ships
  dragon dragonRiders[MAX_RIDERS];  //creates array of dragon/riders.

  for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
      cout << "Rider Name: " << endl;
      cin >> dragonRiders[i].riderName;
      cout << "Dragon Name: " << endl;
      cin >> dragonRiders[i].dragonName;
      dragonRiders[i].dragonHealth = rand() % (20 - 15 + 1) + 15;

  }

  for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
  {
      hunterShips[i].shipHealth = rand() % (40 - 30 + 1) + 30;
      hunterShips[i].numOfPeople = rand() % (15 - 10 + 1) + 10;
  }


  do
  {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)  //Dragons turn
    {
      if(dragonRiders[i].dragonHealth > 0 && dragonRiders[i].isCaptured == false)  //Dragon is alive
      {
        dragonHit = rand() % 10 + 1;
        if (dragonHit <= 7)  //Dragon hits target
        {
          if(hunterShips[i].shipHealth > 0 || hunterShips[i].numOfPeople > 0)
          {
            dragonDamage = rand() % (10 - 5 + 1) + 5; //Amount of Damage done
            cout << dragonRiders[i].dragonName << " hit and dealt " << dragonDamage << " damage. " << endl;

            if (dragonHit <= 3)  //Dragon takes men out
            { 
              dragonRemoveMenNumber = rand() % (3 - 2 + 1) + 2;
              cout << dragonRiders[i].dragonName << "Took out " << dragonRemoveMenNumber << " men" << endl;
              hunterShips[MAX_SHIPS].numOfPeople = hunterShips[MAX_SHIPS].numOfPeople - dragonRemoveMenNumber;  //Ships lose people
            } 

            hunterShips[MAX_SHIPS].shipHealth = hunterShips[MAX_SHIPS].shipHealth - dragonDamage;
          }
          else
          {
            cout << "All ships are destroyed, dragons win!" << endl;
            winCondition = true;
          }

        }

        else //Dragon misses target
          cout << dragonRiders[i].dragonName << " missed" << endl;
      }

      else  //Dragon is dead
        cout << dragonRiders[i].dragonName << " is dead or captured" << endl;  
    }





    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) //Ships turn
    {
      if(hunterShips[i].shipHealth > 0 || hunterShips[i].numOfPeople > 0)  //ship is afloat
      {
        shipHit = rand() % 10 + 1;

        if (shipHit >= 7)  //40% chance to hit 
        {
          if(dragonRiders[i].dragonHealth > 0 && dragonRiders[i].isCaptured == false)
          {
            shipDamage = rand() % (5 - 4 + 1) + 4; //Damage done
            cout << "Ship dealt " << shipDamage << " damage" << endl;
            dragonRiders[MAX_RIDERS].dragonHealth = dragonRiders[MAX_RIDERS].dragonHealth - shipDamage;
          }
          else
          {
            cout << "All dragons are dead, ships win!" << endl;
            winCondition = true;
          }

        }
        else
          cout << "Ship missed. " << endl;
      }

      else
        cout << "Ship is sunk or out of men" << endl; //ship is sunk
    }

  } while (winCondition == true);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I think this is simply a typo. `while (winCondition == true);` means that the loop will only continue while the `winCondition` has a value of true. I think you want `while (winCondition != true);`

Comment: `} while (winCondition == true);` will - of course - exit the loop when `winCondition` is `false`

Comment: In [mcve], even *minimal* is important... I'm too lazy to try to understand all that code where much of it is probably unrelated to your problem.

Comment: This is not a typo. It is a misunderstanding of the condition. It is a "continue" condition, not a "finish" condition.

Comment: @Yunnosch - Threads like this simply demonstrate that people don't actually understand that "while" and "until" have opposite meanings, and write code as if they mean the same.   It would be nice if there was an option to close questions based on a false premise, or a misunderstanding due to inattention.

Comment: @Peter What you describe are beginners questions. They do not exactly match the goal of interesting, well researched, future helpful questions (i.e. those to be upvoted), but they are on-topic questions. Answering them achieves what is the goal of StackOverlfow (nowadays) to attract many more users... The cynical part aside, I really like to teach people basic stuff - those who make an effort. And if you often see this misunderstanding, then feel free to dupe-point here. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is

```
bool winCondition = false;
/* ... */
do {/* ... */}
while (winCondition == true);
```

and you wonder "Loop keeps exiting even though winCondition = false". You also explain "the condition is set to only leave while win condition is true".

I conclude that you misunderstood the semantics of a do-while loop to be "loop until condition is met". Instead it is however "loop while the condition is met". This means that exiting when `winCondition` evaluates to false is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising the `winCondition = false` to start with. The do..while loop will run through one iteration and evaluate that the iterate condition `winCondition == true` is not satisfied, and therefore exit.

In addition, if the do..while loop ever continued, there is no statement inside it where `winCondition` is ever set to `false`, so the loop will never exit.

Did you mean to close the do..while loop with `winCondition == false`?